# What is this small eucalypt-like landscape tree in California?

Tags: identification, trees, pests, dryness

I would like to identify this tree, and particularly to confirm or eliminate it as a possible host for *[Thaumastocoris peregrinus](http://www.cabi.org/isc/datasheet/109741)* recently sighted nearby. The leaves are glossy and have no eucalyptol scent when crushed. The trees range from ~4-8 meters in height and, judging from the area where they've been planted, aren't expected to become very large.

(In the first image, only the two closest trees are the type in question.)

[image: overview]
[image: trunk]
[image: opercula]
[image: foliage]
[image: buds]

Comment: Can you add another photo showing the plant from further away so we can see it's growth habit?

Comment: @Bamboo: Sorry, I was geared up for bug pictures :) I went back better equipped, but the sun was in a bad place... hopefully the added image helps, though. It's a pretty tight space.

Comment: If it wasn't for the crazy flower I would swear it was a Pacific Madrone (_Arbutus menziesii_). I can't believe it

Comment: @BenWelborn: You're right, the bark and foliage are a definite match... weird... maybe somebody's mad science project...

Comment: There's lots of different kinds of simpson's stoppers which are used for urban landscaping... but I'm not sure if that's right either. Again it's about the flowers (close but not exactly). Incidentally, if this tree bears fruit, that would help with ID. Also, regarding the leaves it's difficult to see/say whether they are opposite, alternating, or whorled. Which are they?

Comment: The leaves are alternating, except when they're not... added one more image of opening buds. Also just noticed that there are some extremely similar trees on the property *without* the bud caps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Brisbane Box ([*Lophostemon confertus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lophostemon_confertus)). The flowers threw me off for a bit. The flowers on yours are about done blooming. It's native to Australia, but is cultivated elsewhere. I'm not sure if it's a bronze bug host.

[image]
[image]
[image]